# Can SymmetricDS be used for iOS

Tags: ios, synchronization, database-replication, symmetricds

SymmetricDS has an android sqlite implementation that is awesome.

I was wondering if i **could do the same with iOS** .

I couldn't find anything on their website or on google (basic search spent around an hour).

Also, I was hoping someone could tell me if i could **synch the iOS sqlite from a remote instance of SymmetricDS** and, as to *whether this is a good idea*.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet. SymmetricDS uses Java, which iOS does not support.

However, if you look at this slide deck from April 2013, it says "iOS (Coming Soon)":

https://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2013/sites/default/files/slides/JumpMind%20SymmetricDS%20Percona%20Live.pdf

Ios feature has been assigned on their roadmap:

http://www.symmetricds.org/issues/roadmap_page.php

Answer (score 0):

As of some time well after this question was asked, they did provide an embedded C solution.

See the docs [here](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/user-guide.html#_embedding_in_c_c)

*A minimal implementation of the SymmetricDS client is written in C, which includes a shared library named "libsymclient" and a command line executable named "sym" for synchronizing a database. It currently only supports the SQLite database.*

As SymmetricDS is released under GPL you would need a commercial license.